# SQL grouping by id separated by other ids

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, grouping

I use MS SQL Server 2008 R2.
I have a table:

```
    TypeId    EventDate                 Value      
1.  1         2013-11-01 10:13:00.000   50  
2.  1         2013-11-01 10:15:00.000   10  
3.  1         2013-11-01 10:18:00.000   40  
4.  2         2013-11-01 10:19:00.000   12  
5.  2         2013-11-01 10:21:00.000   545 
6.  1         2013-11-01 10:23:00.000   35  
7.  1         2013-11-01 10:27:00.000   47 
8.  3         2013-11-01 10:30:00.000   3
9.  4         2013-11-01 10:31:00.000   0
10. 4         2013-11-01 10:33:00.000   7
11. 4         2013-11-01 10:38:00.000   35
12. 1         2013-11-01 10:41:00.000   91 
13. 5         2013-11-01 10:45:00.000   37
14. 5         2013-11-01 10:48:00.000   35
```

I'd like to have continuous groups based on TypeId field values, that are not separated by other TypeId values (when ordering is by EventDate).
In this example I want to have seven groups:

- TypeId=1, records 1-3
- TypeId=2, records 4-5
- TypeId=1, records 6-7
- TypeId=3, record 8
- TypeId=4, records 9-11
- TypeId=1, record 12
- TypeId=5, records 13-14

If I use GROUP BY TypeId, I get one group for TypeId=1 consisting of records 1-3, 6-7 and 12

I'd like for example get min and max EventDate for any of these groups:

```
TypeId  MinEventDate              MaxEventDate
1       2013-11-01 10:13:00.000   2013-11-01 10:18:00.000
2       2013-11-01 10:19:00.000   2013-11-01 10:21:00.000
1       2013-11-01 10:23:00.000   2013-11-01 10:27:00.000
3       2013-11-01 10:30:00.000   2013-11-01 10:30:00.000
4       2013-11-01 10:31:00.000   2013-11-01 10:38:00.000
1       2013-11-01 10:41:00.000   2013-11-01 10:41:00.000
5       2013-11-01 10:45:00.000   2013-11-01 10:48:00.000
```

Comment: Show us the expected result

Comment: **Show** us an expected output.

Comment: Add that to your question by editing the post, so that it is readable

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that is fast for big data sets. The CTE calculates the difference between a row number representing `(EventDate)` ordering and a row number representing `(TypeId, EventDate)` ordering, and calls that difference `grp`.  Within each consecutive `TypeId` segment, the difference will be constant, and smaller than the difference that will be produced for the next consecutive `TypeId` segment.

Then a group of `(TypeId, grp)` contains all consecutive rows with the same status:

```
; with  CTE as 
        (
        select  TypeId
        ,       EventDate
        ,       row_number() over (order by EventDate)
                    - row_number() over (order by TypeId, EventDate) as grp
        from     dbo.TestTable
        )
select  min(EventDate) as mn
,       max(EventDate) as mx
,       TypeId
from    CTE
group by 
        TypeId
,       grp
order by 
        mn;
```

<kbd>[See it working at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18c0b/1/0)</kbd>

For more details on this method, see this [sample chapter of MVP Deep Dives](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
With T1 as 
(
select T.*,
 (select TOP 1 EventDate
  from Table1 where TypeID<>T.TypeId
                    and 
                    EventDate<T.EventDate
  ORDER BY EventDate DESC)
  as GrpStart
from Table1 as T
)
Select min(TypeId) as TypeId,
       min(EventDate) as MinEventDate,
       max(EventDate) as MaxEventDate
from T1 Group by GrpStart
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d68bb/4)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks valex, it works! I have to test it on a table with large amount of data, but for small test data it works fine.